# Positioning of \dot

Tags: math-mode, glossaries, italic-correction

When adding a `\dot` above a symbol defined using glossaries, the dot is misplaced. Presumably, the italic correction is not working as expected. How can I fix this?

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{test}
{
    name={$I$},
    text={I},
    description={test}
}


\begin{document}
\printglossaries

$\dot{\gls{test}} \dot{I}$

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Doesnt the dot belong to the symbol and should be *inside* the `gls` argument? Right now, the dot on the outside does not know what is inside the box made by glossaries.

Comment: @Johannes_B not necessarily. I'll often have many variables defined without the dot and then use a generic `$\dot{(\;)}$` entry for "`Time derivative of $(\;)$`", for example. Depending on the field, this can be more or less common.

Comment: @PaulGessler The question is, should `$a$` and `$\frac{d a}/{d t}$` two different glossaries-symbols or not? But this question would not be of a TeXnical nature, right?

Comment: @Johannes_B you are correct that that question would not be of a TeXnical nature. But that is not the question being asked here. The question being asked here is, broadly: I have chosen this convention; can `glossaries` be made to deal with it properly? And that question _is_ of a TeXnical nature. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest something like this:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{test}
{
    name={$I$},
    text={I},
    description={test}
}

\newcommand*{\dotgls}[2][]{\glsdisp[#1]{#2}{\dot{\glsentrytext{#2}}}}

\begin{document}
\printglossaries

$\dot{\gls{test}} \dot{I} \dotgls{test}$

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: off-centre dot I dot I dot I]